# isBlankObject/isEmptyObject AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to get AngularJS to work with IE11. There seems to be a bug with the Foreach function. In it I keep getting the `Object Expected Error`. Heres the code

```
console.log("obj: " + obj);
console.log(typeof(obj));
console.log("isFunction(obj): " +isFunction(obj));
console.log("Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]' ");
console.log( Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]' );
// console.log(  Array.isArrayLike(obj));
console.log("obj.forEach and obj.forEach !== forEach: " );
console.log(  obj.forEach && obj.forEach !== forEach);
console.log("isEmptyObject(obj): " );
console.log(  isEmptyObject(obj));
console.log("typeof Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty === 'function': " );
console.log(  typeof Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty === 'function');
```

and the outputs are:

```
obj: multiple,selected,checked,disabled,readOnly,required,open
object
isFunction(obj): false
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]' 
true
obj.forEach and obj.forEach !== forEach: 
undefined
isEmptyObject(obj): 
---- JS Exception from: IE test staging ----
Error: Object expected
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
Location: resources
Line: 131
```

`typeof(obj)` returns `object`. So why am i still getting this error???
Please help. I'm desperate here.

Comment: M8 problem is IE11 xd

Comment: What is isEmptyObject?

Comment: The error is fired from `isEmptyObject`. But you really should show where you set your variables

Comment: thats the thing. This is the AngularJS v 1.4.7 core library that I am debugging.

Comment: I'm sure Angular 1.4.x works fine in IE11. Post your code which fails, looks like this is **your** code which is a problem. And it's quite obvious that the problem is based on your console.log.

Comment: but thats the thing. my code. like the only 3 lines of code there are 2 console log statements and an include AngularJS line. (I'm using the Crossrider framework btw)
umm what do you mean the problem is based on my console.log? I dont understand that?

Comment: The best thing you can do is to create a demo, maybe. Without it I can only say that *something* tries to use array where object is expected.

Comment: how about i create a new question with my code and maybe you can see if you spot any errors?

Comment: @dsfq also, to answer your earlier question, isEmptyobject is some function  inside the Angular library. I havent been able to dig up anything on it,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150454/including-angularjs-in-crossrider-framework

new question with my code in it.